# Exceeding API request limit

Tags: angularjs, api, url, httprequest, routeparams

I'm using an API data feed for the first time, and it has a request limit of 1000 per hour. This seemed like a lot and I didn't expect to ever exceed it, but just in testing the site I have.

Could this be anything to do with how it is being requested?

It is an Angular application, which uses a Service to call the API endpoint, but the specific endpoint is dictated by a 'team_id' property which exists in an object that is selected on the 'parent' page. I've used $routeParams to pull out that variable and then populate the request URL with that included.

Is this a clumsy way of doing this that is causing 'phantom' requests to occur? As I said I have no idea how the limit was exceeded so is anything else that could be happening here to cause unnecessary API requests in the background?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be tough to troubleshoot unless you post your code that is doing the actual API requests. If you have any loops happening, intervals, or ajax, that could easily multiply your requests into the hundreds on every page view.

Your best bet to troubleshoot is to look at your browser debugger and just look at the http requests in the 'network' tab of your browser dev tools. It will list each individual request for you as they happen (if they are done as an http request / AJAX).

- https://developer.chrome.com/devtools
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628(v=vs.85).aspx